# how to get unique data from multiple columns in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I wanted to get data from 2 columns in below way:

```
Id1 id2 id3
1    1    2
2    3    null
2    4    null
```

O/p

```
Id1 data
1    1,2
2    3,4
```

Here id1 is pk and id2 and id3 is fk of other table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit strange -- concatenating both within the same row and across multiple rows.  One method is to unpivot and then aggregate:

```
select id1, listagg(id2, ',') within group (order by id2)
from (select id1, id2 from t union all
      select id1, id3 from t
     ) t
where id2 is not null
group by id1;
```

Assuming that only `id2` could be `NULL`, you can also express this as:

```
select id1,
       listagg(concat(id2, coalesce(concat(',', id3), '')), ',') within group (order by id2)
from t
group by id1;
```

Comment: I am trying implement above suggested query in db2 but got syntax error. Any suggestions for db2.

Comment: @DeepakSavani . . . `listagg()` and `concat()` are both DB2 functions, so those are not the issue: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_listagg.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this as is:

```
WITH TAB (ID1, ID2, ID3) AS 
(
VALUES 
  (1, 1, 2)
, (2, 3, NULL)
, (2, 4, NULL)
)
SELECT ID1, LISTAGG(DISTINCT ID23, ',') AS DATA
FROM
(
SELECT T.ID1, CASE V.ID WHEN 2 THEN T.ID2 ELSE T.ID3 END AS ID23
FROM TAB T
CROSS JOIN (VALUES 2, 3) V(ID)
)
WHERE ID23 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ID1;
```